# Not getting desired output with VLOOKUP - Need assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, merge, vlookup

I have Table 1, which looks like this -

```
A1  B1  C1
1   X   Date11
2   Y   Date12
3   Z   Date13
```

I have another table, Table 2, that looks like this -

```
A2  B2  C2
1   M   Date21
2   N   Date22
3   X   Date23
4   O   Date24
5   Y   Date25
6   Z   Date26
```

All values in column B1 of Table 1 can be found in some records of column B2 in Table 2. I want to extract the corresponding values in column C2 and place them in Table 1.

So the table that I need is -

```
A1  B1  C1  C2
1   X   Date11  Date23
2   Y   Date12  Date25
3   Z   Date13  Date26
```

I tried using `=VLOOKUP(B1,Table2,2,FALSE)` but that gives me an error. How do I modify the formula to get the result I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `VLOOKUP` searches for the value in the first column of the array you pass to it. Since there are no X'es in the first column of Table 2, you get a `#N/A`-error.

To solve your problem, you need to change the array you pass to `VLOOKUP` to have the values you search for in the first column - and it also needs to contain the column which contains the results you want.

Experimenting a bit with the data you provided, I ended up with the formula:

```
 =VLOOKUP(B2;Table2[[Column2]:[Column3]];2;FALSE)
```

Note that you most likely will need to change the semi-colons in the formula to commas, as it seem we have different regional settings.

Comment: If possible could you take a look at this question too - http://superuser.com/questions/926109/datevalue-gives-different-values-for-similar-data