# DATEVALUE() gives different values for similar data

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007, date-time

In one column, I have timestamps in the format `Jun 10, 2015 11:36:51 AM`

So, to get the date from that column, I created another column and used the formula

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(D2,5,2)," ",LEFT(D2,3)," ",MID(D2,8,5)))
```

So essentially, this operates as follows -

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE("10"," ","Jun"," "," 2015")

=DATEVALUE("10 Jun  2015")
```

This gives me the result `10-06-2015`

Now, in another column, I have obtained dates using `VLOOKUP` as follows -

```
=VLOOKUP(Customers!B2,Customers!B2:B5013:Customers!I2:I5013,8,FALSE)
```

This column also has timestamps of the format `Jun 10, 2015 12:22:48 PM`

I applied the same `DATEVALUE` formula as above to convert this to date -

```
=DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MID(L2,5,2)," ",LEFT(L2,3)," ",MID(L2,8,5)))
```

But this time, I'm getting the value `42165`

Why is this happening?

I want to find the difference between these 2 dates. Hence I want them in the same format.

Answer (score 3):

[Dates in Excel are stored as integers](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/datetime.htm). While you have been confused by how it is displayed in the cell, the value your function returns is indeed the correct one, you just have to change the formatting of the cell to the same as the other one, and they should display the same value.

If you have a look at the dropdown-menu for the format of the cell, you can see that the two are the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Excel a date is always a numeric value. `10 Jun 2015` is `42165`.

You have to change the **column format** to *date*. I guess you are using *General* or *Number*.